# Middle click with touchpad on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, dell, synaptics

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a DELL XPS 13 and my middle click on my touchpad is not working. I tried three-finger-tap and the top right corner.
I even looked in `synclient` and it shows the correct setup... I think.

Do I have to install some additional packages or did I miss something else?
Could it be, that `synclient` has wrong coordiantes for the top right corner?

Comment: The easiest way is to install `libinput`. It uses 3-finger tap for a middle click.

Comment: I installed `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` and had to install `xserver-xorg-core` but this diabled my keyboard

Comment: Well..you probably installed a wrong package because you are using `hwe-16.04` stack. Run `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04`.

Comment: thanks. this package does not disable my keyboard but my touchpad has no more 'tap to click' or the build in gestures... shouldn't there be a way to configure the middle click with  `synclient`?

Comment: You need to enable "tap to click". Hold on, I will write an answer.

Comment: I checked the settings but there the option was not available

Comment: The setting is not where you look for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to install `libinput`. If you are using `hwe-16.04` stack, it can be done by

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04
```

"Tap to click" is disabled by default in the Ubuntu 16.04 by default in `libinput`. You can enable it.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-libinput.conf
```

and add

```
Option "Tapping" "true"
```

to the end of the touchpad section.

In `xorg-synaptics` the multi-finger tapping is unstable in many cases.

Comment: I rebooted after editing the file and my system did not boot. After the Ubuntu splashscreen there was just a blinking `_`. I could enter `tty1` and change it back. Now it is booting.

Comment: This means you made a typo in the file or put the line to a wrong place. It should be before `EndSection` in your touchpad section.

Comment: well the file did not exist, but there is one called `60-libinput.conf`. I changed this file and it works. thank you. Maybe you should edit the answer so other people don't have the same issue. Can I now enable the default gestures (e.g. three-finger-double-tap to change window) or do I have to configure them with another tool?

Comment: Oh, they changed the file name. Other gestures may not be supported by unity. It is another question anyway.

Comment: shouldnt you write a big fat DISCLAIMER in your answer, informing that ther e is serious risk to reboot if a typo occurs?  AND, a comment with "Oh, they changed the filename..."  si a tad flippant, IMO.  Downvoted until you do us the favour of editing.  If and when you do, I'll UPVOTE.  deal?