# Multitouch gestures in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, gestures

I setup my touchpad to middle click with this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896312/middle-click-with-touchpad-on-ubuntu-16-04/).

Now I want to setup some multitouch gestures. I installed touchegg but after starting it does not show any gesture I made...

Is there another tool?

I would like to change the workspace and to display all open windows.